# Show colored compilation errors in C++ on Terminal

Tags: c++, terminal

Is there any way to show compilation errors in colors on the terminal?
I mean when we do "g++ filename.cpp", is there a way to show the compiler messages in colors? By default it is always in Black color. But if we have a lot of error messages, then it helps to have them in different colors (just like the code is highlighted in different colors).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://schlueters.de/colorgcc.html

http://colorifer.sourceforge.net/